# Maven dependency error in Eclipse for Adobe CQ jars

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aem, osgi-bundle

I am using Eclipse Luna with Maven3.2.3 to develop a OSGi bundle for Adobe CQ 5.6.1 project. I was able to resolve most jar dependencies by updating the POM file, except for the CQ classes. I am using the following imports in my code, for which I am still getting the error com.day cannot be resolved.

```
import com.day.cq.commons.mail.MailTemplate;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGateway;
import com.day.cq.mailer.MessageGatewayService;
```

Following is how I created the project using Maven.

```
mvn archetype:generate  -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/    -DarchetypeGroupId=com.day.jcr.vault     -DarchetypeArtifactId=multimodule-content-package-archetype     -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.2     -DgroupId=gel     -DartifactId=gerevamp     -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT     -Dpackage=com.gel.demo     -DappsFolderName=seconddemo     -DartifactName="GEL Formm Servlet"     -DcqVersion="6.0"     -DpackageGroup="GESG Revamp"
```

Below is the dependency I added to the POM file of the bundle

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
    <artifactId>cq-mailer</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However I get the error

> Missing artifact com.day.cq:cq-mailer:jar:5.5.0

Below is a screenshot of the error in the POM. I tried adding the repositories as well to the POM, but that didnt help.
[image: POM Error screenshot]

Please suggest how this can be resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https instead of http in repository configuration. Adobe repository is only working as "https". http request is returning 404 error.

Dependency file is present in

https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/cq/cq-mailer/5.5.0/